# How do I use a different endpoint based on the URL in my Startup.cs file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, endpoint

Im new to .NET and I have a question about using different "home" pages
I have 2 different files in my /views/home/ folder. site.cshtml and other.cshtml
I want to tell may application which one to use based on the URL. Here is the current code in my startup.cs file

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Other}/{id?}"
            );
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
         }
    );

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Site}/{id?}"
            );
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
         }
    );
```

When the application loads it defaults to Other.cshtml as I assume because it's first in the list?

I tried all these combinations and I get File Not Found for all of them? myapplication.azurewebsites.net/Site myapplication.azurewebsites.net/Home/Site myapplication.azurewebsites.net/Views/Home/Site myapplication.azurewebsites.net/Site.cshtml myapplication.azurewebsites.net/Home/Site.cshtml myapplication.azurewebsites.net/Views/Home/Site.cshtml myapplication.azurewebsites.net/?id=Site myapplication.azurewebsites.net/?id=Site.cshtml

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: `chtml` is not a standard extension used in ASP.NET Core, do you want to just serve a static file?

Comment: Maybe combine them `app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Other}/{id?}"); endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Site}/{id?}");`

Comment: You can [edit] your question to correct typos and add more information.